# How can i have two of these audio players on one page, without clicking on one and the other one play or show hide playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the complete HTML

```
<div id="1" class="example">

    <div class="player">
        <div class="pl"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="artist"></div>
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="play"></div>
            <div class="pause"></div>
            <div class="rew"></div>
            <div class="fwd"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="volume"></div>
        <div class="tracker"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="playlist hidden">
        <li audiourl="01.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Artist 1">01.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="02.mp3" cover="cover2.jpg" artist="Artist 2">02.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="03.mp3" cover="cover3.jpg" artist="Artist 3">03.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="04.mp3" cover="cover4.jpg" artist="Artist 4">04.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="05.mp3" cover="cover5.jpg" artist="Artist 5">05.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="06.mp3" cover="cover6.jpg" artist="Artist 6">06.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="07.mp3" cover="cover7.jpg" artist="Artist 7">07.mp3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="2" class="example">

    <div class="player">
        <div class="pl"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="artist"></div>
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="play"></div>
            <div class="pause"></div>
            <div class="rew"></div>
            <div class="fwd"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="volume"></div>
        <div class="tracker"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="playlist hidden">
        <li audiourl="01.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Artist 1">01.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="02.mp3" cover="cover2.jpg" artist="Artist 2">02.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="03.mp3" cover="cover3.jpg" artist="Artist 3">03.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="04.mp3" cover="cover4.jpg" artist="Artist 4">04.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="05.mp3" cover="cover5.jpg" artist="Artist 5">05.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="06.mp3" cover="cover6.jpg" artist="Artist 6">06.mp3</li>
        <li audiourl="07.mp3" cover="cover7.jpg" artist="Artist 7">07.mp3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the complete js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // inner variables
    var song;
    var tracker = $('.tracker');
    var volume = $('.volume');



    function initAudio(elem) {
        var url = elem.attr('audiourl');
        var title = elem.text();
        var cover = elem.attr('cover');
        var artist = elem.attr('artist');

        $('.player .title').text(title);
        $('.player .artist').text(artist);
        $('.player .cover').css('background-image','url(data/' + cover+')');;

        song = new Audio('data/' + url);

        // timeupdate event listener
        song.addEventListener('timeupdate',function (){
            var curtime = parseInt(song.currentTime, 10);
            tracker.slider('value', curtime);
        });

        $('.playlist li').removeClass('active');
        elem.addClass('active');
    }
    function playAudio() {
        song.play();

        tracker.slider("option", "max", song.duration);

        $('.play').addClass('hidden');
        $('.pause').addClass('visible');
    }
    function stopAudio() {
        song.pause();

        $('.play').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.pause').removeClass('visible');
    }

    // play click
    $('.play').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        playAudio();
    });

    // pause click
    $('.pause').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        stopAudio();
    });

    // forward click
    $('.fwd').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        stopAudio();

        var next = $('.playlist li.active').next();
        if (next.length == 0) {
            next = $('.playlist li:first-child');
        }
        initAudio(next);
    });

    // rewind click
    $('.rew').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        stopAudio();

        var prev = $('.playlist li.active').prev();
        if (prev.length == 0) {
            prev = $('.playlist li:last-child');
        }
        initAudio(prev);
    });

    // show playlist
    $('.pl').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.playlist').fadeIn(300);
    });

    // playlist elements - click
    $('.playlist li').click(function () {
        stopAudio();
        initAudio($(this));
    });

    // initialization - first element in playlist
    initAudio($('.playlist li:first-child'));

    // set volume
    song.volume = 0.8;

    // initialize the volume slider
    volume.slider({
        range: 'min',
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        value: 80,
        start: function(event,ui) {},
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            song.volume = ui.value / 100;
        },
        stop: function(event,ui) {},
    });

    // empty tracker slider
    tracker.slider({
        range: 'min',
        min: 0, max: 10,
        start: function(event,ui) {},
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            song.currentTime = ui.value;
        },
        stop: function(event,ui) {}
    });
});
```

I just want the player that you clicked on to play and not all of them at once, same with the dropdown playlist if you click on that all the players on the page open their playlist. Hope i made sense and provided enough info.. if anyone can help please

Comment: You can play an audio by using `new Audio('data/' + url).play();`

Comment: i dont mind the audio or the album art etc..,,but i want to have two or more of these player's on one page, but if you click play all players on the page starts to play, if i click on playlist dropdown all dropdown's of all players dropdown etc...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can try something like this to traverse through the div tree.

```
console.log($(elem).parent().closest('div.example').attr('id'));
```

elem is $('.playlist li:first-child') in your case

```
initAudio($('.playlist li:first-child'));
```